# Running lines of code inside code for new thread instead of specifying a target function to run

Tags: python

I've tried a lot of searching but didn't really know how to word my problem, so it may be that there's a solution that I couldn't find because I didn't know how to search for it.

I have a single line of code that I'd like to run in a separate thread. So far I have the impression that to create a new thread you have to put the code you want to run inside its own function and then call that function using the `target` argument when starting the thread:

```
threading.Thread(target = functionName).start()
```

This is fine and I have it working like this, however because I'm only running a single line of code it seems a bit pointless to have it in its own function, and I'd like to get rid of this. I want to create the thread and effectively specify the actual line of code itself as the `target` instead of the function name.

I can do this in C#:

```
new Thread(delegate()
{
    // any amount of code goes here and it will be run in its own thread
}).Start();
```

But is there any way I can do this in Python?

Comment: So you may use `lambda`.

Comment: @Daniel, one can't put _any amount_ of code in a lambda. No loops, limited control flow, etc.

Comment: @ForceBru: but the OP mentions one line of code, so maybe a lambda is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python you can make inline functions using `lambda`

```
threading.Thread(target = lambda: print('hi')).start()
```

*In this case, note that 'hi' won't show in the terminal as it's in another thread*